# How to add multiple items in model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model called "list" where I have to put several items in it. But I made a code that can put only one item in a list. Can anyone help me solve this?

My model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { itemSchema } = require('./item.js');
const { shopSchema } = require('./shop.js');

const listSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    created: { type: Date, required: true, unique: true },
    updated: { type: Date },
    items: [itemSchema],
    shop: [shopSchema]
});

module.exports.ListData = mongoose.model("listData", listSchema);
module.exports.listSchema = listSchema;
```

itemSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const categSchema = require("./category.js")

const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    created: { type: Date, required: true, unique: true },
    category: [categSchema.categorySchema],
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true }
});

module.exports.ItemData = mongoose.model("itemData", itemSchema);
module.exports.itemSchema = itemSchema;
```

How do I make "items:" to recieve multiple items, not just one? I am using mongodb for this project. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide sample input that you want to insert and currently does not work? It would be better for me to get more insights into it.

Comment: Sure! It would be like this:
POST request:
"name": "TestList",
date is automatically generated,
"items": ["Banana", "Kiwi"],
"shop": "TestShop".
And what it does is that it throws an error because i cannot make an array like that in items. I also tried "items": "Banana", "Kiwi / AND "items": {"Banana", "Kiwi"} / {"Banana"}, {"Kiwi"} and it's not working

Comment: @Omkar my due for this is in an hour and i just saw this mistake... Unlucky

Comment: You have defined `items` field as an array of `itemSchema`. So what is `itemSchema`? The `"items": ["Banana", "Kiwi"]` works if the definition is `"items": [ String ]`, in the `listSchema`. Refer the Mongoose doumentation on [Schema Types](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

Comment: @prasad_ here i added itemSchema

Comment: See [Schema Type Arrays](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays) and [subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#subdocuments) - these have explanation and examples of using _parent_ and _child_ schemas (of MongooseJS).

Comment: @prasad_ i've tried implementing that in my code and it won't work somehow

Comment: @Miloš Milutinov One hint you can get is by running validate function on this schema with available input data. If validation is failing somehow, you might get the error message with what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `items` already accepts multiple items. Is this not what you want? I tested with this little experiment:

```
import connect from './db.js';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

// this just connects to mongodb
await connect();

const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true }
});
const ItemData = mongoose.model("itemData", itemSchema);

const listSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    items: [itemSchema]
});

const ListData = mongoose.model("listData", listSchema);
await ListData.deleteMany({});

// create items
await ItemData.create({ name: "potato" });
await ItemData.create({ name: "tomato" });
await ItemData.create({ name: "kitten" });

const items = await ItemData.find({});
await ItemData.deleteMany({});

// create list
await ListData.create({
    name: "Stuff i luv",
    items
});

// get inserted lists
const q = ListData.find();
q.select("-__v -_id -items.__v -items._id");
const ld = await q.exec();

// print results
console.log(JSON.stringify(ld));

// result is 
[{
    "name":"Stuff i luv",
    "items":[{"name":"potato"},{"name":"tomato"},{"name":"kitten"}]
}]
```